# DotNetOpenAuth NuGet package still recommended for building a .NET OAUTH2 Authorization server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm beginning the R&D (and scoping requirements) to implement an OAUTH2 Authorization Server, and our existing framework is ASP.NET (version 4.6.1 +).  Is there an existing well-exercised SDK for this?  I see that the oauth.net folks are still pointing .NET developers to the NuGet package(s) DotNetOpenAuth, but it looks like the relevant packages there have not been touched since 2013.  Is that just because they are really stable and hence really solid?  Or has the world moved on and I should be looking elsewhere for building blocks for an OAUTH2 server implementation?

Advice very welcome!

Comment: The DotNetOpenAuth project has not been active for quite some time. What did you end up settling on for your SSO solution. @Stephan

Comment: I am also interested in this. DotNetOpenAuth seems stale.

Comment: I ended up deciding DoNetOpenAuth was too risky, and implemented my own Rest framework to follow the spec.  And it is working fine!

Comment: I ran into some SSL/Tls issues with the library after a fresh deployment of our solution to Azure seemed to start working after moving it to Tls 1.0. I'm guessing the packages will need upgraded going forward.